# Showing success icon in RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm putting an icon for notifying user when validation via `RequiredFieldValidator` is failed. I want to know whether it is possible to show an icon if validation succeeds in the place of validation error icon?

I googled but didn't find any direct solutions but instead people were suggesting using custom javascript and catching that icon by using `getElementByID`. Does any direct, `ASP.net`-based solution exist for this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you should use the CustomValidator control.